# mpeg4ip library installation issue in 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install mpeg4ip library in ubuntu 14.04 LTS, whenever I used command **make && make install** it throws error as below. I refferred : Install mpeg4ip on ubuntu 14.04TLS but it shows 404 while updating

```
make[4]: *** [rtphint.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/mp4v2'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib/mp4v2'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/mpeg4ip-1.5.0.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I install this library in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine.

Comment: Full log : [log](https://pastebin.com/index/VtKx1xsd)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please [edit](//superuser.com/posts/1333668/edit) your question and add the log in a code block.